# Issue with Upgrade from Tailwind v2 to v3 React Js using Craco

Tags: node.js, npm, upgrade, tailwind-css, migrate

I was using Tailwind **v2** and when I am upgrading it to **v3** it is giving me Postcss 8 Error **(Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.)**. I tried to resolve this Error but did not succeed. Is there any way I can use Tailwind Cli in React Js.
[Error ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0WU8.png)

```
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.0",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^4.1.5",
    "@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat": "^9.3.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "@manaflair/redux-batch": "^1.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-autocomplete": "^1.8.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "0.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "copyfiles": "2.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "1.32.8",
    "serve": "11.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "dev": "TAILWIND_MODE=watch craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to `rm - rf node_modules` `npm i`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but It didn't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tailwindcss v3 only supports Postcss8 and only create-react-app v5 supports Postcss8 for now. So you need to upgrade the create-react-app to v5.
No need for craco in create-react-app v5 as well

First make sure to checkout to different branch or push your code to github before migrating, just for safety.

1.First run `npm uninstall @craco/craco autoprefixer postcss tailwindcss`
Delete the craco.config.js file
Delete the tailwind.config.js
Now just follow the [offical tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) docs
2. Run `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
3. `npx tailwindcss init -p`
copy paste the tailwind.config.js file from tailwindcss docs
4. `npm install react-scripts@latest`
5. Now `npm start`
6. Change the npm scripts:
"start": "react-scripts start"
"build": "react-scripts build"
"test": "react-scripts test"
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
Later paste your previous tailwind.config theme in the new tailwind.config.js file.

The order of steps may or may not matter but following this steps worked for me.

Comment: These steps worked for me too. The only thing you missed is updating the scripts from "craco" back to "react-scripts".

Comment: these are the scripts for CRA that are missing in the above steps:

"start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",